# GWT automatically create Java Class from UiBinder

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, uibinder

quite new to GWT i was wondering if there's any solution to automatically generate the skeleton for the java class that correspond to a UiBinder.
Basically, i've to create the ui.xml file. from it there's no way to have the structure of the java class? 
do i've to create it by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Intellij IDEA and this IDE provides a menu entry `GWT UiBinder and ui.xml file` to create a java and ui.xml file.

[image: Autogenerate Java and ui file]

If you use eclipse you can read this [article](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/uibinder_composite.html) about the UI Binder wizard.

An other alternative is to create your own file template (every IDE should provide that feature) in order to customize the generated files to your needs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.
I'm using eclipse. I'll try what is in the article (is it a WYSIWYG approach for creating the UiBInder?)
anyway, if you have time, can you explain the template story? i don't know how to do that in eclipse.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I dont know how to do that excatly in eclipse - as I already mentioned I am using IDEA. But after a quick search I found this [article](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ)